# submit button also validates and display an alert dialog

Tags: java, android

In my application i am using a submit button which validates that all fields are inserted or not and then it shows an alert dialog that do u want to save or not.
Here is my code:

```
public void OnClick_click2(final Button btnadd)
{
    final Button btn = (Button) btnadd;
    if(btn.getId()==R.id.btnadd){ 

    if(complain_date_txtbx.getText().toString().trim()
            .length() < 1


                        SaveRecord(data);

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "Your Task saved Successfully!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alert.show();
        }
}
```

It doesn't show a/c to my my requirements, kindly identify where i go wrong and what is appropriate to first on clicking submit button it checks all fields and then display an alert dialog. Kindly guide me

Comment: Has this function being called at all, or it has been called but no alert has been popped out?

Comment: alert is poped out but it is not properly check the condition of if

Comment: @Mona : see in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930870/android-edittext-validation-like-dislog-box/13931234#13931234) post my answer this will help you more

Comment: @Mona : if you have still issue then tell me i will edit your code.

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя: can u tell me how indivisually i can validate each field. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @Mona : first do one thing Create separate  method's for showing alert and for Validation as i have done in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930870/android-edittext-validation-like-dislog-box/13931234#13931234) post

Comment: @Mona : have you done or still facing issue?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя: still facing problem:( can't understand how to make it for each individual field validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove  **";"** from if statement

```
 if(complain_date_txtbx.getText().toString().trim()
            .length() < 1
            || complain_time_txtbx.getText().toString()
                    .trim().length() < 1
            || job_performed_txtbx.getText().toString()
                    .trim().length() < 1

            || next_due_on_txtbx.getText().toString()
                    .trim().length() < 1);  //<<<<<<<<<<
```

because  **";"** terminating if statement execution that's why user is not able to see Toast

**EDIT :** Change your code as :

```
   if(complain_date_txtbx.getText().toString().trim()
            .length() < 1
            || complain_time_txtbx.getText().toString()
                    .trim().length() < 1
            || job_performed_txtbx.getText().toString()
                    .trim().length() < 1

            || next_due_on_txtbx.getText().toString()
                    .trim().length() < 1)
    {
        // show alert here if all fields are empty
    }
    else{
            // show alertbox here
     }
```

Comment: @Mona : most welcome friend :) but you must see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930870/android-edittext-validation-like-dislog-box/13931234#13931234) post for making better validation

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
if(complain_date_txtbx.getText().toString().trim().length() <  && complain_time_txtbx.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1   && job_performed_txtbx.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1   && next_due_on_txtbx.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1)
 {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Please fill all the fields",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you:) you & ρяσѕρєя give me absolute answer